# Permission denied when executing docker commands from Gitlab CI/CD pipeline

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

A CI/CD pipeline is setup in the gitlab with runner on Ubuntu 18.04, with shell executor. When executing docker commands from the pipeline scripts permission denied error is being thrown.

```
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock
```

Already added the `gitlab-runner` user to the root group still the issue is not resolved.

`gitlab-runner` is already running as `root` user also.

```
root      4534  0.5  2.2  36908 23060 ?        Ssl  14:02   0:02 /usr/lib/gitlab-runner/gitlab-runner run --working-directory /home/gitlab-runner --config /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml --service gitlab-runner --syslog --user gitlab-runner
```

Any help to resolve this is greatly appreciated

**Figured out the answer**

`usermod -aG docker gitlab-runner
sudo service docker restart`

Comment: have you tried after reboot?

Comment: @RuwankaMadhushan thanks for the comment, the issues is resolved when I added the gitlab-runner to the docker group.

Comment: kindly add **Figured out the answer** to answers by answering your own question and accept it as well.

Comment: I have added as you said

Comment: Hey, I am using windows 10. how to implement above command. Please advise –

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How to resolve this issue:

```
usermod -aG docker gitlab-runner
sudo service docker restart
```

Comment: Hey, 
I am using windows 10. how to implement above command. Please advise